# Data isn't posted in ASP.NET C# in postback using ViewState

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback, viewstate

I'm trying to post data to the same page after postback with the help of ViewState. I fill out the contents of the page and post the form and display the input on the same page but the validator says that the firstname cannot be null while I just filled out the textbox before I submitted the form.

**Default.aspx**

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="Main" runat="server" EnableViewState="true">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lbl1" Text="First Name" runat="server" />
                </td>
                <td>

                <asp:TextBox ID="tFirstName" runat="server" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ControlToValidate="tFirstName" ErrorMessage="This field cannot be empty."
                    runat="server" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lbl2" Text="Last Name" runat="server" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="tLastName" runat="server" />
            </td>
        </tr>            
    </table>
</div>
<asp:Button ID="id" Text="Submit" runat="server" OnClick="Submit" />
<div>
    <p>
        <asp:Label ID="lTest" runat="server" /></p>
</div>
<asp:Label ID="lSubmit" runat="server" />
</form>
```

**Default.aspx.cs**

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            tFirstName.Text = (string)ViewState["tFirstName"];
            tLastName.Text = (string)ViewState["tLastName"];
        }
        else
        {
            ViewState["tFirstName"] = tFirstName.Text;
            ViewState["tLastName"] = tLastName.Text;
        }
    }

    protected void Submit(object sender, System.EventArgs args)
    {
        try
        {
            lTest.Text = tFirstName.Text + " " tLastName.Text;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have textbox value on page load itself ? which mean make sure your textbox is not null at the beginning of the page.

Comment: @gkrishy I set the value of the text box, but still the validator throws error.

Answer (score 0):

It seems my logic was wrong. The correct condition should be **Page_Load()** function:

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        tFirstName.Text = (string)ViewState["tFirstName"];
        tLastName.Text = (string)ViewState["tLastName"];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be `if (!Page.IsPostBack)` instead of `if (Page.IsPostBack)`

:D

Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

You are getting too confuse on this,

Below is the possible way to solve your issues. Before this, please learn about [postback in page load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(v=vs.85).aspx)

Seems you are passing the null values to the ViewState,

```
    if (Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        tFirstName.Text = (string)ViewState["tFirstName"];
        tLastName.Text = (string)ViewState["tLastName"];
    }
     else
    {
        ViewState["tFirstName"] = tFirstName.Text;
        ViewState["tLastName"] = tLastName.Text;
    }
```

**Proceed as following**

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      if(IsPostback==true)
      {
        if(ViewState["tFirstName"]!=null && ViewState["tLastName"]!=null)
        {
            tFirstName.Text = (string)ViewState["tFirstName"];
            tLastName.Text = (string)ViewState["tLastName"];
        }
      }
    }
    protected void Submit(object sender, System.EventArgs args)
    {
      try
      {
        ViewState["tFirstName"] = tFirstName.Text;
        ViewState["tLastName"] = tLastName.Text;
        lTest.Text = tFirstName.Text + " " tLastName.Text;
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {

        throw;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Say, I follow the first alternative. The values are only set if it is NOT a postback. So how will the values be set in case of postback? Isn't the use of ViewState property to allow us set the values when we DO postbacks?

Comment: The first alternative will not do the trick. Proceed with second one. It will help you to run in the postback event also.

Comment: I tried the first one and it is working alright so far.

Also, in the second option, the data has to be added to viewstate on clicking the submit button?

Comment: You can. But once cookies gets deleted. It won't I guess. Try by deleting the cookies and so on.

Comment: That's your wish(as per requirement) but you can't assign the viewstate when the Text box values are null. Simply it will take the null values as View State.

Comment: I will try the second one and will let you know.

Comment: Sure go ahead. Let me know the final output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57306/discussion-between-nick-s-and-gkrishy).

Answer (score 0):

I only want to point out, that you do NOT have to reassign values to the textboxes after a Postback. This is the normal asp.net web control behavior when EnableViewstate is turned on.

Remove your code from Page_Load and you should notice that textboxes remember values after a postback (unless you specifically remove it in behind code like tFirstName.Text = "")

Comment: what about other input fields like dropdown list, checkboxes etc.

Comment: yes, dropdownlist, checkboxes, checkboxlist, treeview any webcontrol has it's own viewstate where its state is stored.